# Plotting complex numbers and it's conjugate

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, mathcha

I want to plot this in my latex document

:[image]

I have been trying to do it but it has always given me errors, I don't know if my code is right or if I am missing to import something (I already imported tikz).

I have been trying to replicate the graph with the Matcha tool but I can't get the result I am looking for.

```
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt         
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,248); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 248

%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp11352295339791363] 
\draw  (293.4,158) -- (393.4,158)(303.4,68) -- (303.4,168) (386.4,153) -- (393.4,158) -- (386.4,163) (298.4,75) -- (303.4,68) -- (308.4,75)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4318595895682128] 
\draw    (303.4,158) -- (341.96,109.17) ;
\draw [shift={(343.2,107.6)}, rotate = 128.3] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da17611697180317232] 
\draw    (303.4,158) -- (341.36,194.61) ;
\draw [shift={(342.8,196)}, rotate = 223.96] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You already tried something, so please share with us a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This kind of drawing is pretty straightforward in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Matcha is superb for drawing more organic things. For your purpose, it just generate unneeded complex code. Try to do it yourself and post *complete compilable* code. `\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);` draws a diagonal arrow.

Comment: I provided a link to what a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is in my previous comment. I suggest that you have a look to it if you consider posting on TeX-SX in the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to do what you told me, drawing it myself but when compiling I get the following errors:
- Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
- Runaway argument?
- Missing \endcsname inserted.
- Runaway argument?

Answer (score 4):

With `pstricks`, the code is quite short:

```
    \documentclass[border=10pt, svgnames]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl, pst-plot}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(3,2)
    \psset{linejoin=1}
    \psaxes[labels=none, ticks=none](0,0)(-1,-2)(3,2)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={z,\bar z}](2; 40){z}(2; -40){z1}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](z)(z1)
    \psline(z)(0,0)(z1)
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Mathcha this code that is works correctly,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Straight Lines [id:da24929647938311184] 
\draw    (189.3,42.05) -- (189.3,227.05) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4428013785785254] 
\draw    (151.6,132) -- (383.2,132) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da03148052252332034] 
\draw    (189.3,132) -- (269.7,60.55) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8135470928175486] 
\draw    (189.3,132) -- (270.8,201) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp2675997272660642] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (266.07,60.55) .. controls (266.07,58.55) and (267.7,56.92) .. (269.7,56.92) .. controls (271.7,56.92) and (273.32,58.55) .. (273.32,60.55) .. controls (273.32,62.55) and (271.7,64.17) .. (269.7,64.17) .. controls (267.7,64.17) and (266.07,62.55) .. (266.07,60.55) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp07286553192116885] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (266.55,200) .. controls (266.55,198) and (268.17,196.38) .. (270.17,196.38) .. controls (272.18,196.38) and (273.8,198) .. (273.8,200) .. controls (273.8,202) and (272.18,203.63) .. (270.17,203.63) .. controls (268.17,203.63) and (266.55,202) .. (266.55,200) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da10546756418707193] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (269.7,60.55) -- (269.7,157.55) -- (269.7,200.05) ;

% Text Node
\draw (276.7,49.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$z$};
% Text Node
\draw (276.7,193.7) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\overline{z}$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]